# How to rename/store images uploaded to e-commerce application?

Tags: design-patterns

Im writing my first online shop in PHP.  Now working on "add product" form and im not sure know how to store images.

I think i should:

1. check is this image or not
2. resize image to "standard" dimensions used in my shop and generate thumbnail
3. generate unique filename and store image in "images" directory
4. save image with unique filename and insert row into my Images table

I created table with columns like this:

- Id
- Location - url of image - "/0953026326323436324.jpg" for example
- OriginalFilename - original name of file that user was uploading - "myproduct1.jpg" for example

Questions:

1. Is there any better way to do this?
2. Shall i use Id from Images table as unique filename, or shall i stay with generating unique name (by using PHP function)?
3. Shall i generate md5 hash and store it in Images table to avoid/handle duplicates?

Edit 2012-03-03: 
By duplicates I mean files with identical content (but maybe diffrent name).

Im not using any framework, that will be simple and lightweight online-shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your application does with those images. These are some of the things I learnt by experience...

**How many images?**
If we are talking about thousands of images, keep in mind that a folder with that amount of files is probably not accesible via FTP. You can classify them and put them in different subfolders if you need access to them. 
Classification can be done by a number of things... from size to odd/even ID numbers. It all depends on how much you need to split them up.

**Are they private images?** Should they be publicly accesed? If you use just the ID as unique identifier, it's pretty easy to guess and find other images, since they are most likely auto-incremental. You can generate a more secure name in those cases just throwing user IDs, timestamps, random numbers, a hash, or whatever combination...

**Hashing the names?** You don't get any extra security off of this. If you are already using a combination of things of the names, hashing it is just an extra thing to do. Say you are using [image_id]_[timestamp] for the names, if you hash it, you lose that information. You do have it in your database, but it's also good having it in the file names. If for some reason, you need to delete certain files it would be easier if you could recognize them. And, going back to the amount of images you may have... there could be collitions in the MD5. Meaning 2 files would get the same name.. (It's really rare, but it could happen)

---

Since it's a store, I'm guessing you don't need the extra security on the image names, but you might need the extra classification.

Btw, according to your step by step, you can't use the ID of the image for the filename because you insert the row into the table AFTER saving the image.

If you need more details, do leave a comment.

Comment: What you think about my idea of creating MD5 hash from file content, to manage uniqueness of images? You provided very useful tips, but you didnt answered questions - i cant reward you :) Btw - can i reward more than 1 answer?

Comment: Hey, I edited my answer. And no, you can only mark 1 answer as "the" answer. Thanks.

Comment: I know, but i was asking about bounty, not answer/solved. But bounty expired :( I should reward u earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Questions:

1. Is there any better way to do this?.
2. Shall i use Id from Images table    as unique filename, or shall i stay with generating unique name (by    using PHP function)?.
3. Shall i generate md5 hash and store it in    Images table to avoid/handle duplicates?.

Answers:

1. You are using right way.
2. Yes you should use the Id of the image table or you can generate unique name with the help of the id like "id_filename" etc.
3. if you are able to generate unique name for an image why you use md5 hash method.

Comment: I want to use MD5 to check, if there is no the same in system. I dont want to have multiple identical images with diffrent names in system.

Comment: In other words - I care not only for the uniqueness of file names. Do not want to allow the user to load the same file multiple times, regardless of its name.

Answer (score 1):

First check files in client side first. with something like this:

```
function (fileName) {
    var ext = (-1 !== fileName.indexOf('.')) ? fileName.replace(/.*[.]/, '').toLowerCase() : '';
    var allowed = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'tiff'];

    if (!allowed.length) { return true; }

    for (var i = 0; i < allowed.length; i++) {
        if (allowed[i].toLowerCase() == ext) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and in server-side, check file type and resize it using somthing like this:

[Resizing and Extension check](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/upload-and-resize-image-with-php.html)

use this file name pattern:

[ProductId]_[Number].ext

for example: 23_1.jpg and 23_2.jpg (if product has more than one image)

with the above pattern you do not need storing image names for products. you can view product images just by having the ProductId

Comment: I dont want to use product id in image, because my shop administrator may need to use one image for few products (like nails for example - they looks the same, but they have diffrent sizes, material etc.).

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any better way to do this?**

I recently developed something quite similar and this approached worked out really well for me, but this completely depends on your design, goals, code quality, etc.

**Shall i use Id from Images table as unique filename, or shall i stay with generating unique name (by using PHP function)?**

I'd use the id as the filename, since this is always unique, this also mean that you won't have to save it to the database. For example; need the image of product #434? It's images/products/434.jpg.

**Shall i generate md5 hash and store it in Images table to avoid/handle duplicates?**
This is a nice feature, but depending on the amount of images and duplicates, I won't do it. It adds unnecessary complexity to your code with little returns. (This of course changes when you're dealing with 1mb+ images and 30% duplicates, or with very limited/expensive storage)

Good luck!